# map breaking into pieces

Tags: jquery, cloudmade

I am using cloudmade leaflet for my map library. I am not sure how to describe what is happening better so here is an image of what it is doing.

I am embedding it in a jquery slidedown call. Im wondering if it has anything to do with the div size changing but I have the div for the actually map set to 300x400.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is just titled images. I was setting CSS for all image to have a margin. This is turn made all of the image be spaced out as shown above.